# How to sync data between ec2 instances?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Step 1: I have hosted a WordPress blog on EC2 instance using the following doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html)
Step 2: I have created an AMI from WordPress instance
Step 3: I have created a Target group, ALB, ASG.
The second instance starts from ASG but the data of the first instance do not sync with the second instance.

It will be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: " do not sync with the second instance" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I think he want to have 2 ec2 use the same folder. I think Huy should research the nfs because it is easy to apply and can solve your problem

Comment: I find the problem. I resolve that by video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPN37KoAS3k&t=1875s&ab_channel=TheLinuxFever"